# Scrapy setting to use pool of IP?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have a server with multiple IPs attached to it. I tried to find in the documentation, the settings parameter and online, but I was not able to find how I can configure Scrapy to connect to website using one IPs from the pool and rotating from them.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hey, have you tried using this middleware? https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies